# .NET / .NET Core - Is Memory Accessible Externally?

Tags: c#, .net, security, mono, .net-core

If I write a C# app and compile to .NET, or .NET Core, or even Mono, can external apps access the memory in the running process?

I.e. if I write this line of code:

```
var password = "some password";
```

**Could a piece of malware scan through the memory addresses of the process and get the string?**

I guess the question is somewhat OS specific. And, I guess it would also depend on what access privileges the malware has, right? I'm guessing that answer to my question would be different from say MacOS/Linux to Windows, right?

***Edit: Is there any conceivable way of protecting a string in memory? Is there some encryption mechanism that could achieve this?***

One thing I can do to mitigate the problem is to use SecureString. But, it's not perfect:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx#HowSecure

Microsoft's recommended approach is to:

> Instead of using SecureString to protect passwords, the recommended
>   alternative is to use an opaque handle to credentials that are stored
>   outside of the process.

Although, this isn't a concrete answer. It's too abstract for me to understand what they are recommending I do.

Comment: You're basically right.  Some OSes provide better cross account memory access controls between users than others, but processes running as root or the super user account wouldn't be subject to those controls.  It's not a question of the programming language - at the end of the day all memory is accessible to the system.

Comment: Yes. I suppose I could encrypt the string in memory, but then that just passes the problem down... I'd also need to ensure that no process had access to the certificate that encrypts the string. Right?

Comment: The short answer: yes. Of course your app's memory can be read by another process **with the correct privileges**, no matter what OS we are talking about. In C#, things like `System.Security.SecureString` are designed to avoid plain text strings being stored in memory.

Comment: If you have that written in code, I don't even need to scan the active memory of any processes. I can just read the assembly file and scan the metadata and easily get the value.

Comment: Indeed, live debuggers exist. And memory dumps exist. Memory analysis tools based on memory dumps exist. Tools that can forensically look at swap files on a hard disk from when it was suspended: exist. If someone has either physical access to a machine, or administrative access to the OS: you're already insecure. On any OS.

Comment: @SushiHangover but importantly: `SecureString` is known to be readily recoverable via certain tools; it could be a false use of time moving to use `SecureString`

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, absolutely true. I have seen first-hand an exploit kit that actually captures the transitional decoded secure string. It becomes how much of an surface area do you expose to simple scanning...... *personally* I do not use `SecureString`, (IMHO) if an attacker has physical access &| elevated privileges there is nothing that can be done to stop them from accessing memory/swap/files, swizzling methods, etc..

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper In regards to your last edit and your code snippet, are you hard-coding the credential in source, obtaining it via human user-entry, in a network response, etc... ?

Comment: There will be user entry. But, not through a keyboard. There will need to be some kind of obfuscation so as to avoid potential key logging.